# Ajax counter doesn't work

Tags: php, ajax, arrays

All,

I'm working with [this Ajax tutorial](http://www.tizag.com/ajaxTutorial/ajax-javascript.php) which basically pull some records from a database and display them.  I want to modify the code with a button that will show the records one by one instead of together.  The behavior I want to achieve is to get the next record each time the user clicks the `Show next` button.

To do that I have built a little counter in the Ajax function that is used as an index to decide which array element to print.  This doesn't work.  **My question is: why doesn't my counter work?

Here is the html and Ajax code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
<!-- 
function createRequest() {
  //Returns HttpRequest
    return request;
  }

//My attempt at a counter.  This doesn't work.
var index=null;

function calcIndex(){
  if(index==null){
    index=0;
  }else{
    index += index;
  }
  return index;
}
(.....)

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `calcIndex` function declaration is broken, it's missing the `function` part.  And are you *sure* you want to set `index += index`?  That would be sort of odd.  Not only that, even if you fix it and leave it as-is, index will never increment past zero:

```
var index=null;

function calcIndex(){
  if(index==null){
    index=0;            // First call, now index = 0
  }else{
    index += index;     // Second, third, ... nth call: index = 0 + 0
  }
  return index;
}
```

Let's simplify:

```
var index = 0;
function calcIndex(){
    return index++;   // Returns zero first, then 1, then 2...
}
```

But wait, at that point why do you need a function at all?  Instead you can simply do:

```
var index = 0;
...
//index = calcIndex();  No point here
var queryString = "?age=" + age + "&wpm=" + wpm + "&sex=" + sex + "&index=" + index++;
                                                                              ^^^^^^^^
```

Cheers

Comment: You're right, I screwed up the counter.  This being said, I want element 0 to be displayed the first time the button is pressed, then element 1, etc.  I don't think your 2nd and third solution would work...?  I need index to be 0 the first time.

Comment: It will work.  `n++` returns the value of `n`, then increments it.  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/pgJp2/

Comment: Unfortunately, this still doesn't work.  The code stays broken.

Comment: Well, your question was "why doesn't my counter work, and how should I fix it?".  I think I addressed that, no?